# Change animation direction of a centered button on show(duration)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, button

I have a div with some paragraphs that I want to display via .show() on demand. In that div, there is another div, containing a button. That div has text-align set to centered, so that my button is in the middle of all the text in the paragraphs.

When using show(1000), the text animates from top to bottom, which is exactly how I want it. However, the button, instead of following that behaviour, slides in from the left.

```js
$('.showme').show(1000);
```

```css
    .wrapper {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .button {
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .showme {
      display: none;
      width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showme">
    <p>
        Text
    </p>
    <p>
        More Text
    </p>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button class="button">Hello</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the behaviour in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kghn0dx/1/)

I want the button to immediately be in the middle and slide down, together with the paragraphs. How would one achieve that?

EDIT: ... while keeping the Div-wrapper Text Align logic as it currently is. I only want to change how it animates, not how the button is positioned. I need to do it this way in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the button immediately to the middle you should positioned that button.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xgaj2b4/)

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to keep div.wrapper styles without the change but you can remove `position: absolute;` from button you can try to use `$('.showme').slideDown(1000);` -
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgxmL8v0/)

If you want to keep div.wrapper styles without change and also create your own animation you should `.addClass("nameClass")` with your own styles and not to use `.show()`

Comment: Any way to do it without changing the Div logic? (I updated my question)

Comment: But the button animates same as the text when you add long text to your paragraph you will see that also the text is animating from left to ride. Its because the showme wrapper is going from 0px width to 400px

Comment: @SvenEngling I updated the question and I think that the slideDown is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, slideDown actually works. I knew about that function, but I didnt know it also sets the display attribute, so I tried show() before slideDown(), which of course didnt work. I should probably read the docs more carefully next time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS file with this code

```
 .wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.showme {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.showme {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This does the trick. You don't need all the other HTML.
http://jsfiddle.net/zvj3axmf/

Or you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yjacu3bL/
This will fade in the button under the text after the first animation has finished. But it would be better if you solved this with css animations.

Just added a border to show you how this aligns.

Comment: When I use that fiddle, now the entire div slides in from left to right. Thats even worse :D

Comment: @SvenEngling It already did that, you didn't notice because there was no border around it and I centered everything. The `show` function does that by default when you animate it. If you want a different animation you should look at the animation function or just fade in/ out whatever you want. Without centering it mus look like everything works like you want it but it still animates from left top to right bottom http://jsfiddle.net/41yewnov/. As I said you should figure out what animation you want to use https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Comment: @SvenEngling All the better is to avoid jquery animations and use css. Css can basically do everything nowadays, but it takes a little bit more time to get a good grasp on it.

Comment: I'll see if I can get around to really getting into CSS. For now, I followed Joe Koker's answer and used slideDown instead of show, that does exactly what I need. Thank you